# How does command "pmount" work without "sudo"

Tags: linux, permissions, privileges

When I was studying the manual page for command **pmount** I read the following:

> pmount  ("policy mount") is a wrapper around the standard mount program
>          which permits normal users to mount removable devices.

And when I used `pmount /dev/sdc1` (without sudo) as a normal user, it created a folder named `/media/sdc1` folder, while the permissions for the system's `/media` folder are `drwxr-xr-x` and it is owned by `root`. This means that a normal user (currently, me) cannot create files and folders in `/media` folder.

Doesn't this contradict the rules of permissions and ownership in Linux?

Another question is that while `mount` requires superuser permissions, and `pmount` uses `mount` internally, how is it possible to use `pmount` without `sudo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/usr/bin/pmount` is a [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) binary. When running a setuid executable, the uid or gid is changed to executable's owner. When executing pmount, the process will have root privileges and can therefore create root owned directories and mount filesystems.

Same setuid mechanism also applies to sudo.

Comment: Then doesn't this decrease the security of the system? Should I remove "pmount" package and its dependeicnes?

Comment: @Hedayat Yes, setuid binaries can be used by attackers and decrease the security of the system. But without them, you wouldn't be able to do things like change your own password since your password is usually stored securely so normal users can't even read the storage. Some required actions on a system may only be done by setuid binaries - such as using the already-mentioned `sudo` to change to another user. If users need to do what `pmount` provides, you'll need to keep it.  If they don't, yes you would make your system a bit more secure by removing the package.

Comment: Thank you dear Andrew. How can I understand whether a command is a setuid binary or not?

Comment: You can inspect executables /bin /usr/bin with `ls -l` to see if the setuid/setgid bits are set. If you want to find all files with setuid or setgid bit set you can do that using `find` eg. `find / -perm /6000`.